# Invalid identifier when I query in my table

Tags: sql, oracle, navicat

In my table `ALI_LEASE_IN`, I have a `DEF14` field, (sorry about the red frame, choose to DEF16), you can see in my snapshot.

[image]

But when I execute the query sql:

```
select b.equip_name a2,b.model b3,b.def2 c4,b.def3 d5,
  ALI_LEASE_IN.DEF14 as e6,
  '' f7,
  To_char(b.pre_rent) h9,
  b.start_date k10,
  sup.name j11,
  org.name l12, 
  b.memo o13,
  h.bill_date bdate,
  h.pk_group
from ali_lease_in_b b,ali_lease_in h,bd_supplier sup,org_itemorg org 
where b.pk_lease_in=h.pk_lease_in 
  and h.pk_supplier=sup.pk_supplier 
  and b.pk_org=org.pk_itemorg
```

But I got this error below:

```
[SQL]select b.equip_name a2,b.model b3,b.def2 c4,b.def3 d5,  
ALI_LEASE_IN.DEF14 as e6,  
'' f7,  
To_char(b.pre_rent) h9,b.start_date k10,sup.name j11,org.name l12, b.memo o13,h.bill_date bdate,h.pk_group  
from ali_lease_in_b b,ali_lease_in h,bd_supplier sup,org_itemorg org   
where b.pk_lease_in=h.pk_lease_in   
and h.pk_supplier=sup.pk_supplier   
and b.pk_org=org.pk_itemorg  
--and h.pk_org in (parameter('param3'))  
                   --     and substr(h.bill_date,1,10) >= parameter('param1')  
                    --    and substr(h.bill_date,1,10) <= parameter('param2')  
[Err] ORA-00904: "ALI_LEASE_IN"."DEF14": invalid identifier
```

I don't know why, my snapshot shows the DEF14 is exsits in my table.

My environment is :

database is Oracle,
visual software is navicat.

Comment: Try replacing `ALI_LEASE_IN.DEF14` in your select with `h.DEF14`, the field is part of `ALI_LEASE_IN` table, which was aliased as h in your `FROM `clause.

Answer (score 1):

I see your code:

```
from ali_lease_in_b b,ali_lease_in h,bd_supplier sup,org_itemorg org
```

this line you get the table `ali_lease_in` a alias `h`.

So you should use alias, change the line:

```
ALI_LEASE_IN.DEF14 as e6,
```

to :

```
h.DEF14 as e6
```

Answer (score 1):

You have referred to ALI_LEASE_IN for DEF14 when you've have provided a table alias for it. Change that column to h.DEF14 AS e6.

```
SELECT b.equip_name a2,
   b.model b3,
   b.def2 c4,
   b.def3 d5,
   h.DEF14 AS e6,
   '' f7,
   TO_CHAR (b.pre_rent) h9,
   b.start_date k10,
   sup.name j11,
   org.name l12,
   b.memo o13,
   h.bill_date bdate,
   h.pk_group
FROM   ali_lease_in_b b,
   ali_lease_in h,
   bd_supplier sup,
   org_itemorg org
WHERE      b.pk_lease_in = h.pk_lease_in
   AND h.pk_supplier = sup.pk_supplier
   AND b.pk_org = org.pk_itemorg
```